# Outlook 2007 - Missing Out of Office Assistant item on Tools menu

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

We're running an Exchange 2003 Server with Outlook 2007 clients. One of the users does not have the Out of Office assistant on their Tools menu. If I access his account via webmail, I can set his out of office message and status there, but would still love to know why it might be missing and how to get it back on the tools menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking `Help > Disabled Items` , and if the Out Of Office Assistant is in the list, enable it.

Also try looking at Tools > Trust Center > Add-ins

at the bottom of the screen choose Manage 'Exchange Client Extensions' and click 'Go'. Make sure that 'Exchange Extensions commands' and 'Exchange Extensions property pages' are ticked.

If not, try running `Help > Office Diagnostics`

If your outex2.ecf file is missing Office Diagnostics should offer to reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks very much. What worked in my case was to run the Office Diagnostics and then installing the add in again.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the steps mentioned in the below link to setup the auto reply when away from office in the outlook with no out of office assistant.works for outlook 2007
http://www.addintools.com/documents/outlook/howto-out-of-office.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.